# Javascript/jQuery: animation happening twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am writing a simple function to which you pass a jQuery object and then it should turn red, and fade back to its original color.

Here it is:

```
function flash_cell(target) {
  var original_background_color = target.css('background-color');

  target.css("background-color", "#d79795");
  target.animate({ "background-color": original_background_color}, 1500);
}
```

Fairly simple. Or is it ... ? Because when I run the function, it does what it's supposed to.. but then it turns red. Again. Why???

Comment: Okay, if that is not a typo, at least be consistent with your naming :)

Comment: Yeah you're right. didn't notice that

Comment: `animate` by default doesn't animate the _color_ properties. Do you use a plugin? "_All animated properties should be animated to a single numeric value, except as noted below; most properties that are non-numeric cannot be animated using basic jQuery functionality (For example, width, height, or left can be animated but background-color cannot be, unless the jQuery.Color() plugin is used)._"

Comment: @MarcoPrins : give a fiddle....it would be easy from there on...right now its insufficient info! :)

Comment: Yes I do @Vohuman, [jquery ui animate](http://jqueryui.com/animate/)

Comment: Your code works fine as-is in Chrome: http://jsfiddle.net/TrueBlueAussie/voeka8u9/2/

Comment: you most likely call flash_cell twice

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script should work **if**

- you're using **Document Ready** `$(function(){ /*Code here*/ }); // Dom is ready`
- you use **jQuery UI** (Otherwise **background animations** will not happen)
- You're passing into your *fn* a **jQuery Object Element** argument `flash_cell( $("#el") )`

```
$(function(){

    function flash_cell(target) {
      var original_background_color = target.css('background-color');

      target.css("background-color", "#d79795");
      target.animate({ "background-color": original_background_color}, 1500);
    }

    // ___________________________

    var $div = $('div');

    flash_cell($div);         // Do it when DOM is ready

    $div.click(function(){
      flash_cell( $(this) );  // Do it on click
    });

    // No other flashes will occur (unless you click it ;) ).

});
```

**[demo](http://jsbin.com/demazo/1/edit)**

Regarding the element turning red again... probably you're calling your function in different places, hard to say from the code you posted. Explore in detail and you'll find your bug.

Comment: It was beign called from a callback from `$('html, body').animate`, so that was the problem!